# I can't found a way to set up a grafana dashboard with influxdb to monitor a kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, influxdb, minikube

I am currently working with Minikube and trying to set up a Grafana dashboard using Influxdb for the monitoring of my cluster.

I found several tutorials and used this one: https://github.com/kubernetes-retired/heapster/blob/master/docs/influxdb.md as I found many tutorials redirecting to the .yaml here: https://github.com/kubernetes-retired/heapster/tree/master/deploy/kube-config/influxdb

I just modified those `.yaml` a bit, switching all `"extensions/v1beta1"` into `"apps/v1"` and setting the type for the grafana service to NodePort.

But when I am checking the creation of the services and deployments `grafana`, `influxdb` and `heapster` are nowhere to be found.

kubectl deployments created:

[image: kubectl deployments created]

deployments and services not found:

[image: deployments and services not found]

I found this may be because the images I am using are no longer available so I tried using other images like

```
image: gcr.io/google_containers/heapster-grafana-amd64:v4.0.2 for grafana

image: gcr.io/google_containers/heapster-influxdb-amd64:v1.1.1 for influx-db
```

but nothing change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grafana, influxdb and heapster are created in kube-system namespace. So you can find them using:

```
kubectl get pods -n kube-system
kubectl get svc -n kube-system
kubectl get deployments -n kube-system
```

Also the git repository which you are using in archived, I would advice not to use it. Heapster is deprecated in favor of [metrics server](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server).

Comment: Thanks ! I can find them now and it works perfectly !

Comment: I noticed that it is archived yes, I'll chekout metrics server then thanks~